# How to store secret key securely in tizen tv web app?

Tags: javascript, html, owasp, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I'm using XOR encryption in my Samsung smart TV Web application which is use a static secret key for encryption and decryption.

So, what is the best way to store secret?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Web API which could be used for secure storing application data - [tizen.keymanager.saveData](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/5.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/tv/tizen/keymanager.html#KeyManager::saveData).
You can use it for storing some string data and protect this with password - it seems to fit your needs.

Additional feature is that you can share access to this value between several applications, by setting permission.

Comment: I want store static string(file) in the code(before runs the application).

Comment: @VijayKumar There is also a feature of encrypting available in Tizen applications - https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/training/web-application/application-development-process/setting-project-properties#tizen (Encryption property).It protects html, js and css files after installation on the device. Maybe you can use it to somehow protect some sensitive data, but please notice that encryption happen during installation on the device - not during wgt file creation.

Comment: Can you confirm that after the enabling the encryption anyone can not access the sensitive data from wgt file ?

Comment: @VijayKumar the wgt file is not protected itself. Files are encrypted during installation of application and files are just no longer stored by plain text on the device's storage. This cannot be considered as that "anyone can not access the sensitive data". If you need high security you need to consider more sophisticated solution using calls to own server to provide user 'blackbox' encryption.